# Python: Coordinate Conversion

Tags: python, list, coordinates

I have a slice of a set of lists of coordinates a[:,4]. It is in astronomical coordinates, which I'd like to convert to decimal. However, it currently doesn't work for negative astronomical coordinates. I currently have:

```
if any(a[:,4] < 0 ):
    b[:,1] = a[:,4] - a[:,5]/60 - a[:,6]/3600 - a[:,7]/360000
else:
    b[:,1] = a[:,4] + a[:,5]/60 + a[:,6]/3600 + a[:,7]/360000

print b
```

The aim of this is to get it to identify if the coordinate is negative or not from the a[:,4] coordinate and then process the other coordinates one way if it is negative, and the other way if it is positive. However, the "if any" line doesn't appear to be working.

For example, -09:24:40.25 should convert to -9.41118, but it currently converts to -8.58882, as the negative "hours" coordinate is then having the arcminute, arcsecond and milliarcsecond coordinates added to it, instead of them being subtracted.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure *all* the coordinates are negative if any of them are negative? You didn't provide any information about what this list looks like or how it was generated, but the example coord you gave `-09:24:40.25` kind of looks like the degrees would be negative and the remainder positive.

Print out the contents of a[:,4]. Add a print statement that tells you which branch of the if/else is being reached. Some basic diagnostics will help find the problem.

Comment: Well, the easiest thing would be to look into [astropy](http://www.astropy.org) which has packages to deal with astronomical coordinates in a robust way.

Comment: What does `a[:,4]` mean? Seem like illegal syntax too me -- in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `any` function like that assuming you're using a python list, as it takes an iterable and returns true if ANY of that iterable is true

```
a < 0
```

won't return an iterable

replace it with

```
[i < 0 for i in a[:,4]]
```

or

```
 map(lambda x: x < 0 ,a[:,4])
```

so that the if statement becomes

```
if any(map(lambda x: x < 0,a[:,4])):
```

or

```
if any([i < 0 for i in a[:,4]])
```